# Kubernetes pattern canary deployment smoke test best practice?

Tags: kubernetes, canary-deployment

I have a canary deployment process that spinup canary pods and do the smoke test, but as of now, I am running the smoke test against canary pods as well as old pods. I am not sure if I should be doing this, or smoke test should run against only on canary pods?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, but, would appreciate different opinions. Referencing [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/#canary-deployments) that states:

> It is common practice to deploy a canary of a new application release (specified via image tag in the pod template) side by side with the previous release so that the new release can receive live production traffic before fully rolling it out.